# something wrong with Batch program

Tags: batch-file

So I was creating a trivia game with Notepad as a batch file, everything was working great until the end when I was trying to say something and it crashed after they input number 1 or 2 can you please help? Here's my code:

```dos
echo Did You Enjoy?
echo 1. YES!!
echo 2. Not at all :(

set /p enjoy=Your answer here (1-2):
if %enjoy%=1 goto thanks
if %enjoy%=2 goto why

:thanks
cls
echo Thank you! if there were any problems please email me 
pause
goto exit

:why
echo Can you please take the time to email me any problems you had with the program Thanks!
pause
goto exit

:exit
cls
echo test
```

Comment: put strings in quote `set /p enjoy="Your answer here (1-2):"`

Comment: Could you please provide a more specific question title? the current one is totally useless...

Answer (score 2):

```
if %enjoy%=1 goto thanks
```

`==` is the comparison operator, not `=`

Answer (score 0):

You should use ***[EQU](http://ss64.com/nt/equ.html)***  : is an 'Equal To' comparison operator for the [***IF command***](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

And you batch file looks like this one :

```dos
@echo off
echo Did You Enjoy ?
echo(
echo 1. YES ! ! !
echo 2. Not at all :(
echo(
set /p "enjoy=Your answer here (1-2) : " 
if "%enjoy%" equ "1" goto thanks
if "%enjoy%" equ "2" goto why
Exit 

:thanks
cls
echo(
echo Thank you! if there were any problems please email me 
pause
goto exit

:why
cls
echo(
echo Can you please take the time to email me any problems you had with the program Thanks!
pause
goto exit

:exit
cls
echo test
```